# Markarth guards charge me with murder no matter what crime I commit

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Every time I steal something the guards say:

> "You have committed murder and conspiracy against the city of Markarth".

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

If you've ever committed murder in Markarth or the nearby area, and you didn't serve your time in jail or use another way to clear your name, then when you get caught for any crime they'll charge you with ALL your crimes.  Hide your stolen items (so they don't get taken away), then talk to a guard in Markarth and serve your time or pay your fine.  (Or use another method, like bribing the guards through the Thieves' Guild).  From then on, you'll only be charged with the crimes you commit after that.